# KDE text problem with fractional scaling in system settings

Tags: linux, kde, kde5, high-dpi

I have just switched over to KDE because of my new 4k monitors. I turned on fractional scaling and everything looked great. Only one thing stood out. This:

[image]

As you can see the text in the desktop effects menu is just messed up. Also the field in the top right corner is off center. I know it has something to do with fractional scaling as if I set the scaling to 2 it doesn't happen. Any other text looks fine even the rest of the text in system settings. It is only in desktop effects and in a few other sub-menus. Anybody got any ideas how to fix this and maybe an idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced that this only happens with X11 when you set a scaling factor that ends with .25%. For scalings ending with .0% or .5% it seems to be fine. I assume it has something to do with the character spacing of specific fonts, since it seems not to happen with every configuration. With monospaced fonts it doesn't seem to be an issue at all.